# Hausdorff convergence of submanifolds in Riemannian manifolds

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a smooth compact Riemannian manifold. It is well known that any sequence $\{X_i\}$ of compact subsets of $M$ has a subsequence which converges in the Hausdorff metric to a compact subset $X\subset M$.

Assume now that $\{X_i\}$ are, in addition, smooth connected submanifolds with a uniform lower bound on the sectional curvature and a uniform upper bound on the diameter with respect to the induced intrinsic (!) metric.

**Question. What is known about a limit space $X$?**
E.g. should $X$ have an integer Hausdorff dimension?

Remark. Under the above assumptions, the Gromov compactness theorem implies that there is a subsequence converging to a compact Alexandrov space $Y$ in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense (thus $Y$ is not a subset of $M$ a priori). **Is there any relation between $X$ and $Y$?** (I believe there is a 1-Lipschitz map onto $Y\to X$.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right about 1-Lipschitz map, but that is about all you can expect.
In particular the dimension of $X$ might be not integer.

Assume your $X_i$ all isometric to to a flat torus $\mathbb{T}$ and
$M=\mathbb{E}^N$; that is your manifold is the Euclidean space of high enough dimensions $N$.

By Nash and Whitney, any short map $\mathbb{T}\to \mathbb{E}^N$ can be arbitrary well approximated by an isometric embedding.

It reamins to construct a short map $\mathbb{T}\to \mathbb{E}^N$ with non-integer Hausdorff dimension. 
An image of that type is shown on the picture.
It can be arranged that the Cantor set on the top has Hausdorff higher than 1 and lower than 2. 
[image: FRACTAL-3d-FLOWER],

Comment: But by Nash and Whitney, the isometric approximation of the short map is only $C^1$-smooth. That probably means that $X_i$ are not infinitely smooth submanifolds. Can one make them to be infinitely smooth?

Comment: @sva No, I use the other theorem of Nash --- if $N$ is large, you can do the same for $C^\infty$ embeddings.